# how to generate typescript interface as string

Tags: typescript

i want to generate interface to string.
example

```
interface cat {
    id : number
    name : string
}
const output = convertInterfaceToString(cat)
```

my expect output should be a string exactly like this
" interface cat {
id : number
name : string
} "

My purpose is to generate an interface as a string in my project and then save it to a file (e.g., somefile.ts). This way, I can use it in another project without the need for manual copying and parsing.

is it possible in typescript? thankyou.

Comment: Why you want to create as string, why copy entire file from 1 project to another.

Comment: This is not possible in TypeScript directly.  You'd need some other build step that looks at your source code and does something with it.  TypeScript interfaces are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types) along with the rest of the static type system, so there's nothing you can use to create the string you're looking for.